Terminal does not open on Ubuntu when using updated python version, only works with specific version
I have these versions of python installed under python:
1.
update-alternatives --list python
  /usr/bin/python3
  /usr/bin/python3.11
  /usr/bin/python3.12
  /usr/bin/python3.8
  /usr/bin/python3.9




update-alternatives --list python3
  /usr/bin/python3.10
  /usr/bin/python3.12
  /usr/bin/python3.8

When I change the python version for python3 to python3.12 (Any version other than 3.8), the terminal doesn’t seem to work.
I can’t open the terminal.
So then I open the virtual terminal using ctrl+atl+F3, and change the python version back to 3.8 with the command:
update-alternatives –config python3

And select python3.8  - Then the terminal starts working again
Why is the terminal attached to python3.8? I may have to work with python’s other versions.
When I change the python version for the python it causes no problem. It’s only with python3
Can somebody who has a deep understanding of Ubuntu and Python guide me?

which terminal ? How do you start terminal?

@GiacomoCatenazzi Both the Default and Terminator on Ubuntu.

Maybe you added some scripts (configuration, or at start-up of shell, e.g. .bashrc, .profile) which call some programs/scripts which depends on python3.8 (I would say: it will hang instead of failing)

@GiacomoCatenazzi Haven't added any script to .bashrc or .profile

In any case, check. You may not have added anything, but some programs tend to do bad things (convenience but bad designed). But maybe the question may be better answered in Unix and Linux Stack Exchange (one sister site of us, link on top right icon)

@GiacomoCatenazzi I've posted on Ubuntu Stack Exchange

Reposted here: Terminal does not open on Ubuntu when using updated python version, only works with specific version - Ask Ubuntu

The duplicate on askubuntu is at a much better place. This question isn't about programming. Also it's heavily Ubuntu-specific, not just the update-alternatives tool but also having a Python wrapper in front of GNOME Terminal is specific to Ubuntu (or maybe Debian too).

if Ubuntu was installed with 3.8 then better don't replace it with any other version because some functions, programs and services may need to run python3 and they may need modules which are installed with version 3.8. It may even crash all system. If you want to use command python3 then create venv for project and then inside this venv it allows to use command python3

@furas: All versions are installed with Ubuntu, and update-alternatives is supposed to be used by users to change defaults. If systems requires a specific version, it will call explicitly such specific version. -- Note: bugs happen, but in this question it seems not a corner case, but something python-team should have tested

What does it mean "to open a terminal". Which terminal are you using on Ubuntu? If it is the gnome terminal, you just double click the Gnome Terminal icon.
